# Failed audit - unclear really?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I failed this audit as I knew exactly what the OP was talking about. https://askubuntu.com/review/close/399092

I failed because no one else did. I suppose this just underscores why humans are needed for these tasks that we perform but isn't it just a bit annoying to have a pile of switches tell you that you aren't paying enough attention when it seems the reverse is true?

Comment: I disagree with some of the audit questions, but,that is the way the cookie crumbles when the community is responsible for moderation. You have to fail several to be banned from audits, so just use it as a learning experience.

Comment: If you keep reviewing, you'll eventually notice that the review audits have all kinds of little quirks causing those reviews to present you with information that is not quite entirely consistent. This will become even more obvious, if you follow the link from review audit to the actual question. The two will never look exactly the same. If you pay enough attention to the right things, you will be able to recognize review audits, and comparing the review page with the actual question will even give you a very strong hint which action is considered correct.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You are obviously correct. I overreacted to the fact that what was painfully obvious to me wasn't to others. I have no doubt that I have in the past voted to close questions that were unclear to me that may have been painfully obvious to others. I edited the question for clarity and voted to reopen which I should have done instead of venting here.

Comment: As a side note, I'd like to mention that the original post (look at the edit history: "your help stinks") seemed more like an excuse to rant than a real question. I am not sure, but I might have initiated the "unclear what you're asking" procedure. That's the risk when your question is hidden in dirt.

Comment: @JacobVlijm    Good point

Comment: Offtopic: I don't understand a word of your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Community user randomly puts tests into the review queues. This is to check whether the reviewers pay attention and do their work right. A single mistake has no consequences, but many of them may lead to a review ban.

It just takes posts that were reviewed earlier by real humans and found to be not worth keeping on the site for whatever reason. (There are also sometimes highly upvoted posts taken that require a positive review. Sometimes they also don't really deserve their high rating.)

So not the Community bot, but those people who flagged the original posts for deletion are the ones to blame for the inappropriate result. Sometimes deletion flags are controversial and maybe the post is not clear for everybody. Then it can happen that the wrong people get the wrong post in the queue and enough flags accumulate to delete a question which could have been saved.

That's not good, sure, but how should we prevent it? By increasing the number of reviews necessary to delete a post, our queues become more and more ineffective. Already now, the Close Vote Queue often grows up to 1000 entries.

Comment: IMHO the only way to prevent it is to pay attention.  I don't think increasing the number of reviews necessary is a viable option. It's just a bit disconcerting to be overruled by the masses who aren't. I'm not concerned personally about a review ban, what's sad about that particular question is the user had a genuine (verified at least by me) problem and was dismissed so abruptly that his perhaps justifiable anger is clear if you bother to read the edit trail. It's sad to lose a member of the community because the job is too overwhelming for some to bother to attempt to do it right.

Comment: The reopen votes seems to be underutilized =) You can always flag a question to re open

Comment: The question I am directed to in the link is still open.

Comment: @ElderGeek There was absolutely 0 way of telling exactly what the OP was referring to by "Ubuntu start page", the post was rightfully closed. For all we know he could have been referring to lightDM. People even left nice comments. The system deciding to use the post as an audit so quickly concerns me however..

Comment: @Seth I beg to differ. I submit that everyone who has installed Ubuntu in recent years has  seen : http://imgur.com/SQfUlVb  Be that as it may I share your concern regarding the audit system.  I'm certain that I over-reacted to the fact that what was painfully obvious to me wasn't to others. I have no doubt that I have in the past voted to close questions that were unclear to me that may have been painfully obvious to others. I edited the question for clarity and voted to reopen which I should have done **instead** of  venting here.

Comment: @Seth have the recently changed the formula?

Comment: @Tim Not that I am aware of.