# Confused with a review entry

Tags: support

I'm confused with [this review entry](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/733254)

[image]

I remebered this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926539/what-does-the-character-mean-in-bin-sed-e-sabczzzg) because I actually saw it like one month ago.
So I want to the question to review the answer but it isn't asked "2 hours ago" but is already old and not from a new user

[image]

Is it possible that a new User just copied the answer from Ravexina and reposted an exact copy or is this some review bug? Why do I get this for reviewing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed audit - unclear really?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13799/failed-audit-unclear-really)

Comment: not exactly dublicate because I didn't "fail" and that wasn't my question ... but yes the answer given there make things clear. anyway I got an answer already thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's an audit.**

If you click the "link" hyperlink right under the "answered today," it will take you to the answer by Ravexina.

The system changed the name and such to ensure that you don't base your decision on who posted it and/or when it was posted.

---

> [image]

Comment: Ah ok I get it ... so it's kind of a "test" for reviewers? This is really confusing especially because I saw the question and the answer before but wouldn't have thought this is intentional ... seemed rather like a bug to me...

Comment: @derHugo Yes, exactly.

Comment: @derHugo It's a test to make sure you're paying attention and not robo-reviewing and just marking things as passed or failed without paying attention.  That's all.